# I have a "license" in my package.json, why is npm/yarn saying it is missing?

Tags: javascript, node.js, package.json, yarnpkg

On running `yarn install` I see a warning every time that there is no license filed even though I have defined one:

```
$ jq . package.json 
{
  "name": "license-example",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "main": "index.js",
  "license": "UNLICENSED",
  "dependencies": {
    "lodash": "^4.17.4",
    "moment": "^2.18.1"
  }
}
```

which according to the [npm defintion](https://docs.npmjs.com/files/package.json#license) should be valid:

> Finally, if you do not wish to grant others the right to use a private
>   or unpublished package under any terms:
>
> ```
> { "license": "UNLICENSED" }
> ```

Here's the output:

```
yarn install
yarn install v0.27.5
warning ../package.json: No license field
[1/4] Resolving packages...
success Already up-to-date.
Done in 0.09s.
```

My main goal is for that warning to disappear, yet I also don't want to provide an invalid open-source LICENSE to make the warning go away, even if it is an internal project that never will be seen on the outside.

How to mark a yarn project as proprietary without a warning appearing?

Comment: Weird. Don't see how it could happen, if it is configured properly. yarn basically checks it it is a string: https://github.com/yarnpkg/yarn/blob/e177c3732e6cd2adb468427d06a3bbcd2a5e4356/src/util/normalize-manifest/validate.js#L78  Try to set `{"private": true}` to skip the check entirely.

Comment: I don't think it's `.license`. It's `LICENSE` - all caps, no extension.

Comment: Double checked, and couldn't reproduce. Is the any chance to get a made-up package.json that reproduces the problem?

Comment: @AlexBlex I just generated a example project, same behavior. See updated question for package.json. I'm on Ubuntu by the way, can this may be a bug related to the OS?

Comment: tested on 16.04 with the package from the question. No warnings: `node_modules/.bin/yarn install \n
yarn install v0.27.5 \n
[1/4] Resolving packages... \n
success Already up-to-date. \n
Done in 0.28s. \n
`

Comment: @AlexBlex Thank you for your feedback. It made me look at the problem from a different angle, and I found the solution. I've added it as an answer.

Comment: The question solved my problem! You get a +1 for that.

Comment: I think "PROPRIETARY" would be slightly better than using "UNLICENSED". This site (https://cpl.thalesgroup.com/software-monetization/proprietary-software-license#:~:text=A%20proprietary%20license%20model%20is,Photoshop%2C%20Skype%2C%20and%20more.) has a good description of a PROPRIETARY license: A proprietary license model is based on the concept that the software company creates software and maintains control over its code, and therefore, its features and use.

Answer (score 237, accepted):

For `yarn` and `npm`, the default behavior is that they look up into the parent directories.

I had an outdated and forgotten `package.json` in my home folder without a license field:

```
~/package.json
```

When running `yarn install` within my project:

```
~/my-project/package.json
```

`yarn` then also found the one in my home directory and reported the error for that one. I mistook that for my project's `package.json`.

The warning makes that clear by preceding the path with `..` for the parent folder.

```
warning ../package.json: No license field
```

After removing that outdated `package.json` I get the expected output:

```
yarn install v0.27.5
[1/4] Resolving packages...
success Already up-to-date.
Done in 0.88s.
```

Comment: Very helpful! It keeps me puzzled whether people writing those warnings really hate their job...  why not simply write a more clear warming like 
"warning ../package.json **in a parent directory**: No license field"?

Comment: Hah, related: I had this warning every time I opened a shell, turns out I had a `package.json` after executing yarn in my home folder (because `cd` is hard). Thanks for the answer!

Comment: It works! But isn't this dangerous? After all, if you have a typo and type "UNLICENSE", your whole code will be in the public domain! Isn't there a more failsafe expression than "UNLICENSED"?

Comment: Thanks for this, I had package.json in my home directory and that's why I was getting the warning.

Comment: Adding `"private": true` to the `package.json` file is the correct way to prevent this warning, in a typical case where your software is proprietary and not meant to be licensed to the public or published. The accepted answer is a pretty extreme edge case. See other answers below.

Comment: It might be an edge case @AndrewKoster but I had the same issue although more like ../../../../../../ and the local package did have the private set to true?

Comment: I had a `package.json` and  `package-lock.json` on my `/home` dir, deleting those solves the problem. 
                                                                                                         - Ubuntu user

Answer (score 55):

Take a closer look at the message:

> warning ../package.json: No license field

It's referring to a package.json one directory level higher.
Fix that one by either entering a license field or a private: true or delete it because it probably should not be there anyway ;-)

Comment: Yes, I got a `package.json` a directory higher. After deleting it the warning was gone.

Comment: Wow. Thank you. I wasn't paying attention. Mine was ../../package.json. Why on earth is yarn walking UP the directory tree two levels? That seems like very strange behavior since I have a package.json in the same folder I ran the command from.

Comment: I had a tiny `package.json` for some reason in my home directory. I've been living with this warning for years. Thanks!

Answer (score 30):

I was getting the following warning along with some other licensing warnings.

```
warning package.json: No license field
warning react-material-dashboard@0.3.0: No license field
```

All I did was, update the `package.json` file's `private` property to be `true`.

```
{
  "name": "some-application-name",
  "author": "Keet Sugathadasa",
  "email": "email",
  "license": "MIT",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "private": true,
  ...
}
```

With this, I no longer got any `No license field` warnings when I do `yarn install`. To understand why, please see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/61725516/4388776).

`{"private": true}` means, that npm will refuse to publish it, to prevent accidental publication of private repositories.

For more on this, see the following links.
https://docs.npmjs.com/files/package.json#private
https://flaviocopes.com/package-json/#private

Answer (score 18):

After trying multiple solutions, i found there were following files in root, need to delete:

```
cd ~
~$ rm -rf package.json
~$ rm -rf yarn.lock
~$ rm -rf package-lock.json
```

Comment: To clarify, @Tahir is deleting `package.json` files not associated with any project, as mentioned in [Gernot's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64956962/2430657). You should not run these commands if your project happens to be in your home directory (which is not a recommended place to put your project).

Answer (score 10):

I am new to the react, but I find, the most simplest way is: just add the `"private": true`, to your `package.json` file. That's it.

Answer (score 8):

I got stuck in the same error and I found that when we add `package.json` or `yarn`, some files can be there in the system roots. So, the errors are from there the system root. You can simply remove those files and the error will not be there anymore.

1. just cd ~, then you can find package.json & yarn.lock.
2. rm -rf package.json or rm -rf yarn.lock

Answer (score 0):

If the error persists, just check your system root at C:\Users\User you will see a package.json and yarn.lock files, delete them, the warning will go. These are the files interfering with your project

Comment: OP isn't necessarily on Window OS, so your answer should target other OS, too.
Furthermore, although your suggestion is good - it doesn't always work

Answer (score 0):

Yarn is broken and needs to be fixed.  UNLICENSED is a valid designator for the license field, but yarn does not recognize it because the developers have not kept that up to date.

Note this answer is 6 years after the question was posed.  But they have not prioritized this update.

Just tested this with a package.json containing:
private: true,
license: "UNLICENSED"

on yarn version 1.22.19

and the warning still appears.  Best thing to do is ignore the warning it is simply a nuisance.
-- Updates --
Note it has been suggested that adding --ignore-scripts can turn off this warning, but it doesn't ONLY turn off this warning it has other consequences.

By not treating UNLICENCED as an equally valid entry as ISC for example, this warning can encourage some very harmful engineering practices in an enterprise environment such as selecting the default open source license for code that is being developed as proprietary work for hire code for an employer.  This can pose a serious risk to that employer's ability to retain ownership of IP they have paid good money to develop.

Comment: you can use the ```yarn install --ignore-scripts``` to prevent Yarn from running any post-install scripts, including the one that checks the license field.

P.S:
If you are sure that your project doesn't need to execute any post-install scripts and the "UNLICENSED" license field is intentional, this should work for your needs. However, it's always a good practice to specify a valid license if your package is intended for distribution and use by others to avoid potential licensing issues.

Comment: Be sure to do some more research before posting an answer.

Comment: If UNLICENCED is a valid field which my answer states and you reiterate that it is, then you should not have to turn off features in order to avoid warnings.  You don't have to use --ignore-scripts if you use other types of license fields such as ISC, and some code is never intended for distribution.  No further research is required.  --ignore-scripts can turn off other features you want in order to avoid a warning that should not happen.  Your suggestion carries unintended side effects.  Engineers often apply OS licenses to proprietary code to work around this issue, which is harmful

Answer (score -2):

Just make sure you are in the directory that contains the package.json file, then just **yarn** or **npm** install then **serve** it as you please.

I am currently running a project without the license field and it works perfectly,
I don't think that can return an error.

Also, see more information regarding the mandatory fields you need for your package to run and other tips regarding the package.json file with **yarn/npm**:

```
https://classic.yarnpkg.com/en/docs/package-json/

https://docs.npmjs.com/files/package.json
```

Answer (score -3):

I had similar issue, i just upgraded the version of Node and every thing worked fine.....

Comment: Hi Sybghat. Could you explain what version had the issue and what you updated to?

Comment: i had version 8 and updated it to 10
I followed Following Steps:
1- sudo apt install curl
2- curl -sL https://deb.nodesource.com/setup_10.x | sudo -E bash -
3- sudo apt install nodejs

Comment: I've moved your comment into the answer. Please feel free to edit it however you think best :)