# Why does "No license field" Warning Disappear when you set "private": true in your package.json

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, yarnpkg, package.json

I have a react application that installs its dependencies via `yarn install`. When I run this command, I get the following `No license field` related warnings.

```
warning package.json: No license field
warning react-material-dashboard@0.3.0: No license field
```

Then I updated, the `package.json` file's `private` property to be `true`. (See [NPM docs](https://docs.npmjs.com/files/package.json#private))

```
{
  "name": "some-application-name",
  "author": "Keet Sugathadasa",
  "email": "email",
  "license": "MIT",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "private": true,
  ...
}
```

Now, all warnings related to `No license field` disappeared. **Why?**

Comment: Because a `private` package will not be distributed and therefore doesn't need a license!

Comment: Also, you spelled `license` incorrectly. It's `license` with an `s` not `licence` with a `c`

Comment: @phuzi, Updated `license`. Thanks. I think you answered my question. If you can post it as an answer with a description, to help others as well. I can accept it.

Comment: For what it's worth, [react-material-dashboard@0.3.0](https://github.com/micrum/react-material-dashboard/blob/v0.3.0/package.json) didn't declare any license in package.json (current version does).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The warning complains about there not being a `license` field (with an `s`), you do however have a `licence` field (with a `c`), correct the spelling and the warning should disappear.

The reason that setting `"private": true` works and prevents the warning from appearing is that private packages don't get distibuted and therefore do not need a license.

Comment: Spelling mistake fixed it. And thanks for sharing that `license` field is ignored when `"private": true`.

Answer (score 0):

UPDATED: FIXED - CD into the right directory, I was in the parent directory

Old issue:

This did not resolve my issue, in the terminal I see:

```
homefolder@MacBook-Pro LFHome % yarn start
yarn run v1.22.19
warning package.json: No license field
error Command "start" not found.
info Visit https://yarnpkg.com/en/docs/cli/run for documentation about this command.
homefolder@MacBook-Pro LFHome %
```

Even though I changed the package.json to:

```
{
  "name": "seventhave",
  "email": "email",
  "licence": "MIT",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@fortawesome/fontawesome-svg-core": "^6.2.1",
    "@fortawesome/free-solid-svg-icons": "^6.2.1",
    "@fortawesome/react-fontawesome": "^0.2.0",
    "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^5.16.5",
    "@testing-library/react": "^13.4.0",
    "@testing-library/user-event": "^13.5.0",
    "react": "^18.2.0",
    "react-dom": "^18.2.0",
    "react-scripts": "5.0.1",
    "web-vitals": "^2.1.4"
  },
```